# How to retrieve previous row column value along with given column value in pandas

Tags: pandas

Below is my dataframe

```
S2BillDate      totSale     count
0   2020-03-01  27880.21    796
1   2020-03-02  45664.74    1278
2   2020-03-03  41554.50    1170
3   2020-03-04  42929.59    1239
4   2020-03-05  49113.58    1380
5   2020-03-06  46945.72    1328
6   2020-03-07  12706.32    455
```

If my input is `2020-03-07`, how can I retrieve the value above it, ie in this case `2020-03-06`.
Also How can i use `get_value()` to retrieve 'totSale' to the corresponding date ?

Is there any easier way to achieve it via pandas itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) in order to performance a [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m = df['S2BillDate'].eq('2020-03-07').shift(-1, fill_value=False)
```

---

```
   df.loc[m]
   df.loc[m, 'S2BillDate']
   df.loc[m, ['S2BillDate', 'totSale']]
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrive the value(s) above '2020-03-07':

```
df['S2BillDate'][df.S2BillDate.tolist().index('2020-03-07')-1]
>>> '2020-03-06'
df['totSale'][df.S2BillDate.tolist().index('2020-03-07')-1]
>>> 46945.72
```

Comment: I think we don't need convert to list in order to indexing.. I think you could be interested in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 0):

This could be a simple solution:

```
In [65]: df['S2BillDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['S2BillDate'])
In [67]: df = df.set_index('S2BillDate')

In [69]: s = '2020-03-07' ## input value
In [70]: s = pd.Timestamp(s)

In [73]: loc = df.index.get_loc(s)
```

#### `get_value()` is now deprecated, do below instead:

```
In [79]: df.iloc[loc - 1]['totSale']                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[79]: 46945.72
```